# Skype display picture saving

Tags: skype, contacts

How can I save the display pictures of my friends and mine from Skype?

Comment: I'm assuming you tried right-clicking on their picture and you weren't able to do it that way?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://community.skype.com/t5/General-Discussion/My-Profile-Pic/m-p/200606#M2303)'s a program you can use to get *your* profile picture. I'm still looking for a way to get friends' profile pictures.

Edit: Oh, wait, that can get contact's avatar's too.

Once you have that API running, you can get your Avatar with the command

```
GET AVATAR 1 <filename>
```

To get a contact's avatar, use the command

```
GET USER <skypename> AVATAR 1 <filename>
```

Answer (score 2):

[This post on the Skype community forums](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/How-do-I-get-some-of-my-friends-skype-picture/m-p/1656130/highlight/true#M153926) has some useful information.  In particular, I found this helpful:

> The easiest way is to open this link in your browser:
>
> http://api.skype.com/users/contactname/profile/avatar
>
> Just replace “contactname” with exact Skype name of the contact.

There are some other helpful tips as well.

Comment: Doesn't work. Always show a same default image,

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy the entire screen with the <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> (print screen) keyboard key, then paste and edit it with Paint. Cut the specific region of the photo and paste in a new Paint window.

If you want to automatically copy just an area of the screen, there are many options of [screenshot software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot_software) you can look up and try.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
Public Function GetUserImage(ByVal SkypeID As String) As Bitmap
    Dim app As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\Skype\Avatars\"
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(app) = False Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(app)
    End If
    Dim command0 = New SKYPE4COMLib.Command()
    command0.Command = String.Format("GET USER {0} AVATAR 1 {1}", SkypeID, app + SkypeID + ".jpg")
    oskype.SendCommand(command0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) 'Allow the system to write the image to disk
    Return New Bitmap(app + SkypeID + ".jpg")
End Function
```

To get the profile image just use this within a button or whatever

```
Picturebox1.backgroundimage = GetUserImage(oskype.friends(1).handle)
```

**NOTE:** This causes writes to the disk via IO operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a MacOS users, [This discussion](https://community.skype.com/t5/Mac-archive/Where-is-the-profile-pic-stored/td-p/4006780) shows where Skype's avatars are saved locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every method mentioned in other answers, some are not working and some are not simple. Here I provide a simple answer which I discovered today.

Skype now have a web app. You can login into your account and do whatever you do with Skype PC applications. The web apps are purely html codes. So you can easily drag drop any image from webpage. There are many option to download a image from webpage.

So here is the steps I followed,

1. Goto https://web.skype.com/
2. Login into your account
3. Click on the Contact Name/Your Name to View Selected Profile
4. Right Click and save the Profile Image